# Angular animation getting applied on element rearrangement

Tags: angular, animation

In ngFor, I am using angular "trigger" property to imitate the accordion behavior in angular.

Initially, I am hiding all the list elements with animate state as "hideEle" but on specific element click, I am showing that specific element with animate state as "showEle".

This works as expected but on moving elements up or down using up/down arrows, the hideEle=>showEle animation is getting applied in angular.

I had also used trackBy to provide an unique id to each angular element but the issue remains the same.

```
trigger('toggleState', [
      state("showEle" , style({ background: "#f1f2f6" })),
      state("hideEle" style({ height: '0', padding: 0, display: 'none' })),
      // transition
      transition('showEle => hideEle', animate('500ms ease-in')),
      transition('hideEle => showEle', animate('500ms ease-out')),
    ]);
```

Initially the element is hidden with

> display: "none"

Any Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Create sample demo on "Stackblitz"

Comment: can you show the template?

Answer (score 0):

Added a void state and transition (hideEle=>void) for removing the unwanted animation.

```
state("void", style({height: 0, display: "none"})),
transition("hideEle <=> void", animate("500ms ease-in"))
```